# How can I define a key map which switches to one of two split windows and then peforms a non-normal mode command?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I am working in two split windows in vim. I would like to define a key map which will switch to the other window, paste the contents of some register onto the top of the file in that window, and then perform a non-normal command on that file (such as sorting the contents of the file via a call to bash sort).

I am able to define a mapping which performs the first two tasks, but I do not know how to add a non-normal command to the end of the map.

The command I am using to switch to the window (below) and paste the latest yank onto the top of the file is (in command mode):

```
:exe "norm ^Wbgg0P"
```

Now, I can concatenate a non-normal command to the end of this (without defining a mapping) like so (note that the last command is non-normal):

```
:exe "norm ^Wbgg0P" | exe 'norm gg0vG$' | '<,'>!sort
```

But my question is: how can I define a key map with the above command as the "rhs"?

I tried the following, but it does not seem to work (there was no error message, but the map does not appear to be getting defined properly based on the behavior when I press `<F5>` afterwards):

```
:map <F5> exe "norm ^Wbgg0P" | exe 'norm gg0vG$' | '<,'>!sort
```

Comment: Why not just `:nmap <F5> <C-W>bgg0P`?

Comment: Thank you, melpomene. Your suggestion answered my original question, but the issue arises when I need to add non-normal commands after the original command on the "rhs".

Comment: `|` is interpreted as the end of `map`. Use backslash to escape.

Comment: To expand on @Matt's comment, see `:help map-bar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ex command in `{rhs}` of a map, you must start it with `:`, and end it with `<cr>`

You should use `norm!`, the `!` prevent mapping.

Use `noremap` unless you know `{rhs}` should be further scanned for mapping.

`%` equals to `1,$` in `:h :range`

At last there is `:h :sort`, it sorts all lines if you don't give it a range.

```
nnoremap <F5> <c-w>bgg0P:sort<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the particular case above. I am still not clear on how to append additional ex commands to the end of this, but I will read the documentation referred to by Randy above for more on that.